# Run comments_template() function in Wordpress Plugins

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I include the comments on the page afterwards with ajax, required code is in the plugin, but comment_template() function does not work when the request goes plugin file, Ajax request is successful, but there are no comments.

Codes that go to Ajax are as follows.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_comment_update_get','comment_update_get'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_comment_update_get', 'comment_update_get');

function comment_update_get(){

    global $withcomments;
    $withcomments = 1; 
    $post = get_post($_POST['post_id']); 
    comments_template();
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/comments_template/):

> Will not display the comments template if not on single post or page,
>   or if the post does not have comments.

If you take a look at the [source code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L849), you'll notice that the `comments_template()` function checks whether we're currently on a post or a page, or if the **global** `$post` object is set up.

So:

```
function comment_update_get(){

    // Set up our required global objects    
    global $post, $withcomments;

    $withcomments = 1;
    $post = get_post( $_POST['post_id'] );

    // Load the comments template
    comments_template();

    // We're done here
    wp_die();

}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_comment_update_get','comment_update_get' ); 
add_action( 'wp_ajax_comment_update_get', 'comment_update_get' );
```

Comment: If so, then please [accept my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) @Totgeist.